Why do we use "views expressed" instead of "expressed views"?
I saw some sentences with "views expressed".
Could anyone explain why do we use "views expressed" instead of "expressed views"?
Examples:

It is intended to reflect the richness and diversity of the views expressed.

Views expressed are solely my own and do not express the views or opinions of my employer.


Thanks.

See also past-participle-after-noun-proposed-cost-vs-cost-proposed.

Views (that have been) expressed!!

Making expressed a postmodifier indirectly emphasizes that there is someone expressing the view. The "expresser" is closer to the surface, as it were, because as a postmodifier it is the past participle of the verb, as a  clause, and transitive verbs have a do-er, an agent, whereas  as a premodifier usage has converted that form into an adjective, an attribute of the noun it modifies.

What @TimR said. Note that the "attributive" form becomes more natural when contrasting the past participle based adjective with a more straightforward adjective, as in It's easier to argue against expressed views than implicit views. And it's much more natural when preceded by an adverb: It's easier to argue against explicitly expressed views than implicit views.
